# what is the part of speech of the word home in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I have to diagram the sentence:

> The work stops when it rains, and most of the men go **home**.

What is the part of speech of home, and where would it go on a diagram?

Comment: I'd say it's an adverb, as with *When it rains we go inside.*

Comment: "Home" and "inside" are prepositions.

Comment: From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home#h2) (and I assume any dictionary): "**home** adverb, **1** : to or at one's place of residence or home // told the dog to go *home* // stayed *home* all day"